# Prevent newline after header, but not before

Tags: html, css, header, jekyll

I have a situation where I want a paragraph that looks something like this:

> **The Header, in Bold** Some information about the topic at hand...

I want a new line before the header but it to flow into the paragraph.

There are two ways I can think to achieve this:

1. Use a `<br />` tag.
2. Wrap a paragraph tag around the header and make the header fully inline.

The problem is (2) is hard since I have little control over the HTML, which is generated from Markdown in the Jekyll framework.

(1) is often viewed as bad practice but it may be the way to go here.

Is there a better option?

## Edit

Closing as duplicate; using `float` is the answer.

Comment: sticking <br/> tags all over the mark-up is never a good answer

Answer (score 3):

```
<h1 style="display: inline-block;">Header</h1>
<p style="display: inline-block;">paragraph</p>
```

This should allow you to have them both on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<p><span style="font-weight:bold">The Header, in Bold </span> Some information about the topic at hand...</p>`

Comment: The question specifies that the HTML is generated from Jekyll.

Answer (score -3):

```
 <b>This is a Heading</b>
 <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

or

```
 <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: The first example is poor html. `<b>` is an inline element and *it is not* something to be used to make something look like a header. That is what header elements are for…

Comment: okay , tell me , you want to use header and paragraph in same line ?? because other answers are saying to use in same line. But I thought as per your question that you want to use in Different Line.